# Is it possible to stream windows applications to Linux via VNC?

Tags: linux, streaming, vnc, terminal.app

Is it possible to stream windows applications to Linux via VNC?

Need only some apps not a whole desktop.

Comment: You want a SSH client like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), a server like [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/). VNC works on a system basis, SSH on an application level.

Comment: Also, I corrected a little bit of your terminology - it sounded a little weird earlier, and you're technically streaming a desktop, not the whole OS.

Comment: @new123456 thanks. But it's a normal and popular term "Application streaming"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, no, currently it's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about Application Virtualisation, I believe. Something like the Citrix apps used in many corporate environments?

VNC is designed for controlling entire computers using remote desktop. Virtualizing individual applications usually has very different requirements, including an application server. With the right tools I know it is possible. Citrix applications can be run using Java on the client computer, and so Citrix-virtualized Windows apps can be accessed and used in Linux and MacOS.

What I not sure of is if the work necessary to build an application server is worth the benefit you may enjoy.

However, if you want to dive in, X Server appears to be a relatively long-lived application virtualization system that works with Windows. As with many old Open Source products, there are many variants with different strengths and weaknesses. I found out about it simply by googling "open source application virtualization" and following a few links.

UPDATE Adding suggested X Server flavor:
Xming seems to be the most user-friendly version of XServer and it is compiled both for Windows and Linux, which means it'll probably fit your bill compatibility wise.
http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/

UPDATE Adding details regarding further research into Xming:
Hmmm, reading through some of the xming man pages, I see it appears to be for virtualizing linux applications for access and display on a windows client rather than the other way around, such as it seems you're looking for.

I didn't see anything that says xming WON'T virtualize Windows apps, and I haven't read all the documentation yet. But at least the first part of the documentation seems to only show how to configure Linux apps for virtualization and Windows for the client/display side.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response, for your time! The link you provided is extremely useful, though it's not really related to the question. I made a research and found out that there are some solutions like www.2x.com (weird though, for example, when you launch the app windows welcome message plays). And of course leading software is XenApp by Citrix, but it's very expensive.